# OneDrive shared folder deltas

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

As described in the "Remarks" section in [Track changes for a Drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#remarks)

> - In OneDrive for Business and SharePoint, `delta` is only supported on the `root` folder, not on other folders within a drive.

But when I use delta request on the root of a drive that I got permissions to one of the inner files (not including the root folder itself), It results in an incorrect delta result.

For example, the root looks like that:

- `root`

  - `folder1` (shared with me)

    - `file1`
  - `folder2` (*not* shared with me)

    - `folder3` (shared with me)

      - `file2`

In this situation I was expecting the delta request on the `root` will give me `folder1`, `file1`, `folder3` and `file2` but it doesn't.
The request return only `folder1` and `file1` but ignore `folder3` and its children. Probably because it stops searching for deltas when it get into `folder2` that is not shared.

If I try to call the delta request on the folder directly it results in an error, as expected.

Is there a workaround?